# How to create a AAA triptik?

Tags: software-rec

The ones among us that remember the 2400 baud modem, will also probably remember the TripTiks that were produced by AAA.  So if you wanted to take a road trip, you just went down to your local AAA office told them where you wanted to go and they produced an awesome booklet for you with road maps. Each page of the booklet had about 50-100 miles of the road. The opposite side of each page contained all attractions and points of interest within 10-20 miles off the road.  It made for an interesting trip and reduced the monotony of the road.

I tried to find a software product that does what the TripTiks did 20 years ago (particularly, I am interested in the along-the-road points of interest), but could not find it (Google Maps or Microsoft Streets & Trips don't seem to have this feature).

Can someone point me in the right direction? (mild pun intended)

Comment: Every GPS unit available can view attractions of all sorts in any area it covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motel 6 has a feature on their website for planning trips that includes attractions (and Motel 6's) along the route. I'd bet many hotel sites offer similar services. AAA.com offers similar functions as well, but I believe you have to be a member.

Yahoo! has a trip planning function that even works in Europe. I used it 5 years ago to plan a Italy trip.

Doing a google search for "Road Trip Map" returned several other promising results that may be worth a check.

Comment: Is this a suitable answer?